# Configure Jenkins Global Pipeline Library via Groovy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can a Jenkins *Global Pipeline Library*, which can be configured in the Jenkins master, be set up using Groovy code?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Derived from the great answer of StephenKing, here is the new way to do for the ModernSCM using [`GitSCMSource`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/37a95884ac7855c252be736f4d8e93e1e296f803/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/git/GitSCMSource.java):

```java
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.SCMSourceRetriever;
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryConfiguration;
import jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMSource;

def globalLibsDesc = Jenkins.getInstance()
        .getDescriptor("org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.GlobalLibraries")
SCMSourceRetriever retriever = new SCMSourceRetriever(new GitSCMSource(
        "someId",
        "mygitrepo",
        "credentialId",
        "*",
        "",
        false))
LibraryConfiguration pipeline = new LibraryConfiguration("pipeline", retriever)
        .setDefaultVersion(env.BRANCH_NAME)
        .setImplicit(true)
globalLibsDesc.get().setLibraries([pipeline])
```

Answer (score 8):

The config can be accessed via [`org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.GlobalLibraries`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin/blob/34af216440292fddcbcc2a5fa13a4e96a12b40fe/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/libs/GlobalLibraries.java):

```java
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.*
import hudson.scm.SCM;
import hudson.plugins.git.*;

def inst = Jenkins.getInstance()
def desc = inst.getDescriptor("org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.GlobalLibraries")
```

Assuming a Git repo, we can define the SCM as follows:

```java
SCM scm = new GitSCM("https://git.example.com/foo.git")
SCMRetriever retriever = new SCMRetriever(scm)
```

Every library is an instance of the [`LibaryConfiguration`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin/blob/34af216440292fddcbcc2a5fa13a4e96a12b40fe/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/libs/LibraryConfiguration.java), which is finally added using `setLibraries()`:

```java
def name = "pipeline"    
LibraryConfiguration libconfig = new LibraryConfiguration(name, retriever)
desc.get().setLibraries([libconfig])
```